# What an Exclamation do before src - HTML

Tags: phpstorm, intellisense, script-tag

In PhpStorm, I just noticed that while using intellisense for `script` tag PhpStrom autocomplete it to following:

```
<script !src="">
</script>
```

So whats this `!` do before `src`?

Comment: 1) PhpStorm version? 2) How did you type/complete it? 3) Is it reproducible in brand new empty project?

Comment: PhpStorm 9.0. Just type 'scri' and hit Ctrl + space in a php file, it will give you two options. One with normal `src` and other with `!src`.

Comment: I see what you mean -- it's one of the Live Templates for HTML. Unfortunately I do not know what that `!` is doing there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, please follow [WEB-17980](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17980) for updates